# what's the difference between $SL(2,C)$ and $PSL(2,C)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Am I missing something? what's the difference between $SL(2,C)$ (matrices 2x2 complex coefficients and determinant 1) and $PSL(2,C)$ which is isomorphic to $PGL(2,C)$ (matrices of complex coefficients with determinant 1)?
Are $PSL(2,C)$ and $SL(2,C)$ the same?

Comment: ok... I got the problem with taking in account only the determinant...., but I leave the question if someone made the same mistake

Comment: $PSL(2,\mathbb C) : = SL(2,\Bbb C)/\{ \lambda \mathbb1 \mid \lambda\in \Bbb C^\times\}$. Basically $PSL_2$ is $SL_2$ with the centre divided out.

Comment: The $2\times2$ identity matrix $I$ and its negative $-I$ are two different elements of of $SL(2,C)$, but they represent the same element (equivalence class of matrices) in $PSL(2,C)$ and in $PGL(2,C)$.